# Reading all data from stream of TcpClient

Tags: c#, stream, tcpclient

I am working on a new machine at my works which is controlled via a PC. Current stuck on talking to a camera system that is connected via Ethernet.

Here is my code of opening a connection.

```
TcpClient client;
NetworkStream stream;

public bool OpenConnection()
{
   client = new TcpClient();

   try
   {
      //Camera.Open();
      client.Connect("192.168.0.10", 8500);
      stream = client.GetStream();

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       return false;
   }
    return true;
 }
```

So far so good. Once the connection is open I then request some information from the camera
The message format I am using has STX(0x02) to indicate the start of the message and ETX(0x03) as the end of the message.

```
    char StartOfPacket = (char)0x02;
    char EndOfPacket= (char)0x03;

    public bool RetrieveDigits(out string Digits)
    {
        // Send the trigger cammand to the vision system
        Digits = "";
        bool EverythingOK = true;
        string DataToSend = StartOfPacket + "T1" + EndOfPacket;
        byte[] buff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DataToSend);

        if (LogCameraEvent != null)
            LogCameraEvent(">> " + DataToSend);

        try
        {
            stream.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.Instance.LogExceptionToFile(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex);
            EverythingOK = false;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(100);

        byte[] buffer;

        if (EverythingOK)
        {
            // Check the response
            buffer = ReadCamera(10);

            // Process the packets
            string[] packets = ProcessPackets(buffer);

            if (packets != null)
            {
                if (packets.Length > 0)
                {
                    bool TriggerFound = false;

                    for (int i = 0; i < packets.Length; i++)                            
                        {
                            if (packets[i] == "T1")
                            {
                                TriggerFound = true;
                                continue;
                            }
                            else if (TriggerFound)
                            {
                                // If we are here then we should now be the data that was requested
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(packets[i]))
                                {
                                        Digits = packets[i-1];  // previous packet may have data from previous trigger. Need to look into why this happens.
                                }
                                else
                                    Digits = packets[i];
                                EverythingOK = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                                EverythingOK = false;
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No Packets Recieved");
                    EverythingOK = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Packets Recieved");
                EverythingOK = false;
            }
        }

        return EverythingOK;
    }
```

Here is the part where I think the issue may lie, getting the response.

```
    private byte[] ReadCamera(int ExpectedLength)
    {
        if(ExpectedLength < 1)
        {
            ExpectedLength = 100;
        }

        byte[] Buffer = new byte[ExpectedLength];
        int read = 0;

        int chunk;
        while(stream.DataAvailable)
        {
            chunk = stream.Read(Buffer, read, Buffer.Length-read);

            read += chunk;

            // If we have reached the end of our buffer, check to see if theres any more information
            if(read == Buffer.Length)
            {
                if(!stream.DataAvailable)
                    return Buffer;

                // Nope. Resize the buffer, put the byte we've just read and continue
                byte[] newBuffer = new byte[Buffer.Length * 2];
                Array.Copy(Buffer, newBuffer, Buffer.Length);                    
                Buffer = newBuffer;
                //read++;
            }
            else if(!stream.DataAvailable)
                return Buffer;

            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        // Buffer is now too big, shrink it
        byte[] ret = new byte[read];
        Array.Copy(Buffer, ret, read);
        return ret;
    }

    private string[] ProcessPackets(byte[] data)
    {
        // look for the stat char
        List<string> Packets = new List<string>();
        byte Start = 0x02;
        bool StartFound = false;
        byte End = 0x03;            

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i =0; i<data.Length; i++)
        {
            if(StartFound)
            {
                // Check to see if its the end
                if (data[i] == End)
                {
                    Packets.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Clear();
                }
                else
                    sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(data, i, 1));
            }

            // Find the start
            if (!StartFound)
            {
                if (data[i] == Start)
                {
                    StartFound = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return Packets.ToArray();
    }
```

Let me explain what should happen and then what is happening. Through `RetrieveDigits` method I am sending "T1" to the camera. What the camera will do is respond with "T1" followed by 2 ascii characters, for now we will say AA. Using a diagnostic app on the camera system I can monitor the Ethernet and I see the following.

(>> means Received by Camera)
(<< means Sent from Camera)

```
>>[STX]T1[ETX]
<<[STX]T1[ETX][STX]AA[ETX]
```

So I see what the camera has sent. I confirmed the PC has has received the data using wire shark.
Now further down in the `RetrieveDigits` method you can see I process the packets received, loop through the packets until I find "T1" and then assume the next packet will be the data I am after and I set `Digits` to this value.
What I am finding is that sometimes when I run the app I see that `Digits` is set to "".
I am also finding that sometimes my data received will be "AA" then "T1" rather than "T1" then "AA". What I suspect is happening is that when its back to front, the "AA" is actually from the previous data sent from the camera and for some reason it was missed when reading from the stream.

Any idea why this could be happening as I am reading the data until Stream.Available is false.

Edit:
Modified the `ReadCamera` code to process the packets, reading 1 byte at a time.

```
private string[] ReadCamera(int ExpectedLength, int ExpectedPackets)
    {
        List<string> Packets = new List<string>();            
        bool StartFound = false;            

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if(ExpectedLength < 1)
        {
            ExpectedLength = 100;
        }

        byte[] Buffer = new byte[ExpectedLength];
        int read = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            read += stream.Read(Buffer, read, 1);

            // Check to see if the byte read is the start of a packet
            if (Buffer[read - 1] == StartOfPacket)
            {
                StartFound = true;
            }
            else if (StartFound)
            {
                // Check to see if the byte read is the end of a packet
                if (Buffer[read - 1] == EndOfPacket)
                {
                    Packets.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Clear();
                    StartFound = false;

                    if (Packets.Count == ExpectedPackets)
                        break;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(Buffer, read - 1, 1));
                }
            }
        }            

        // For Debuggin purposes
        foreach(string s in Packets)
            if (LogCameraEvent != null)
                LogCameraEvent("<< " + s);

        return Packets.ToArray();
    }
```

and modified calling the method like so

```
// Check the response
string[] packets = ReadCamera(10,2);

// Process the packets
//string[] packets = ProcessPackets(buffer);
```

Comment: While I doubt this is related, I would recommend using `using` blocks with `client = new TcpClient();` and `stream = client.GetStream();` since they implement IDisposable.

Comment: DataAvailable is almost always a mistake. It does not do what you think it does. Remove it from your code entirely.

Comment: @BradM Thanks for the comment, normally I do this and recommend this but in the case of my application I am polling the camera system so I manually close the stream else where when its no longer required.

Comment: @usr Thanks for the info, do you know of an alternative way?

Comment: There is inherently no way to tell when the other side has completed sending because any moment it could send another byte. You can either Read until you get zero bytes (end of stream) or until you can detect from the bytes read that a message is complete.

Comment: @usr I have taken what you have said on board and changed the code to read 1 byte at a time. As I have the advantage of knowing how many messages/packets I should receive each time, I know process each byte looking for the Start and end of a message. I will post the modification later after further testing but so far so good.

Comment: @Gaz83 I'll take a look then. Socket programming has many usage rules that are not obvious. I have never seen a tutorial that explains everything you need to know.

Comment: @usr although not .NET specific, this one answers alot of questions: http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/

Comment: You must deal with the situation that stream.Read can return zero. In that case the remote side has finished sending. Also, it is by far more well-performing to read bigger buffers. That is not a correctness issue though.